Ellipsis `...` to list of unevaluated expressions
How can I write a function in Base R to capture the dot-dot-dot (ellipsis) and return a list of unevaluated expressions?
In this example, the user supplies expressions in curly braces, and receives the output I need:
fun1 <- function(...) {
    as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]
}
fun1({a = 2}, {a2 = a * 2})
> [[1]]
> {
>     a = 2
> }
> 
> [[2]]
> {
>     a2 = a * 2
> }

I would like the user to make the same call as above without curly braces and receive the same output as in fun1():
fun2 <- function(...) {
    # CODE HERE
}
fun2(a = 2, a2 = a * 2)


This sounds like an XY problem. What exactly do you need this for? Do you require the function to accept arguments of the form name = expr, or do you want to accept arbitrary expression, and what do you want to do with the result?

Adding to my previous comment, depending on your use-case there are different approaches to solving this. One particular one is taken by ‘box’, which expects arguments of the form name = expr.

Yes, I agree. I'm trying to meet very specific requirements for a proof of concept, but will try to convince the principal that there are better ways. Thanks for the link, I'll take a look.

Don’t get me wrong: I’m not saying that what you are doing is a bad idea, or generally not feasible (though user2554330 has correctly explained R’s syntactic limitation here!). Actually one other way around the dilemma is to use <- instead of = assignment (though personally I wouldn’t do that, since I impose a strict ban of <- in my own projects).

You can't easily do that, because the = in the first example is an assignment operator, while the = in the second example just binds expressions to names -- they are different kinds of things.
If you really want to convert the arg list into a list of assignments it's possible, by manipulating the expressions.  I don't recommend this, because it changes the meaning:
fun3 <- function(...) { 
  args <- as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]
  names <- names(args)
  result <- args
  names(result) <- NULL
  for (i in seq_along(args))
    if (nzchar(names[i]))
      result[[i]] <- call("=", as.name(names[i]), args[[i]])
  result
}

fun3(a = 2, a2 = a * 2, 123)
#> [[1]]
#> a = 2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> a2 = a * 2
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 123

Created on 2024-07-13 with reprex v2.1.0

Thanks for the solution. Your warning is very sensible.

I like the warning and the way you approach this but implicitly coercing the output of nchar() to a logical value reads like Python to me. I would prefer to use here if(nzchar(names[i])).

@SamR:  that's a good suggestion, I've changed it.  BTW, I think C was more of an influence on my thinking than Python!

Update: adding some solutions to original answers to match the expected output
This is a bit hackier of a solution that relies on rlang

fun2 <- \(...){
  random_things_from_users <- as.list(substitute(rlang::enquos(...)))

  random_things_from_users <- random_things_from_users[-1L]

  print(random_things_from_users)
}

fun2(a = 2, a2 = a * 2)
#> $a
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $a2
#> a * 2
fun3 = \(...){
  
  user_args = as.list(substitute(rlang::enquos(...)))[-1L]
  
  user_names <- names(user_args)
  
  args_from_users <- purrr::map2(user_args,
                                 user_names,
                                 \(args, user_names) as.name(glue::glue('{user_names} = {deparse(args)}')))
  
  names(args_from_users) <- NULL
  
  
  
  args_from_users
}


fun3(a = 2, a2 = a * 2, b = 'hello world')
#> [[1]]
#> `a = 2`
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> `a2 = a * 2`
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> `b = "hello world"`


fun4 = \(...){
  
  user_args = as.list(substitute(rlang::enquos(...)))[-1L]
  
  user_names <- names(user_args)
  
  args_from_users <- mapply(\(args, user_names) as.nameglue::glue('{user_names} = {deparse(args)}')),
                            args = user_args,
                            user_names = user_names)
  
  names(args_from_users) <- NULL
  
  args_from_users
}






Created on 2024-07-13 with reprex v2.1.0

Thanks, but your fun2() does not produce the same result as fun1(). Yours returns a named list where the a= part is the name, rather than having the assignment inside the expression itself. (Also, I edited my original answer to specify that, in this application, I need base R only. Sorry for that!)

I think this fun2() does produce the same result as fun1(), and that's the problem.  To get the result shown here you just need the original  as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L].

@Vincent got it no worries! I updated my answer to include a solution to match the expected output.

Sorry, but I think it's worse now.  Now you return things with names like a = 2.  That shouldn't be a name! it should be an expression.  Honestly, I think Vincent's original as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L] is the best solution so far, better than yours, better than mine.

Ahh I see what you mean! Basically if we wanted to we could grab it from the list and it would run evaluate it later. I made the mistake of storing things in the list as a character matching the output in the console but not the desired result . Sorry for clogging up everyone's notifications with this! Was fun to work through though
